# rtsp stream of an IP camera is much more delayed in VLC than in the NVR

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I have an IP camera that i can view in VLC via the link `rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.199:554/mpeg4/ch0/main/av_stream` but i noticed there is a significant delay to the video in vlc compared to when the camera is viewed in the NVR. The vlc has a delay of 4-6 seconds while in the nvr its barely noticeable at all  less than 1 second of delay.

I need to know why that is so i can then plan out what methods/libraries to use in the program im going to make. It helps to know why so that a possible work aroung maybe explored.

Is this a problem inherent to vlc or a limitation to rtsp?

Is there any way i can reduce this delay?

Comment: Just assuming here, but VLC uses network buffering for better playback. By default it is 1.5 seconds. Have you played around with it?

Comment: @BijayRegmi yes i did, i went as far as setting it to 0 and the delay is still around the 4-6 second.

Comment: Have you tried `RTP over RTSP` streaming instead of default `HTTP based` streaming in `tools -> Preferences -> Input/Codecs`

Comment: @BijayRegmi I have tried to set it as you have said and still no significant improvement

Answer (score 1):

First get sure that your camera has no issue with getting multiple streams. Deactivate your camera on NVR and check if you have a better latency.

VLC use per default rtsp/rtp over TCP so force vlc to use rtsp/rtp over UDP just google about the vlc argument.
And verify if u have better latency.
As BijayRegmi wrote be aware of the default buffering.

Also you can try ffplay from ffmpeg libary and open the rtsp stream with it. There u have more informations about the health of the stream like package loss etc. Also this gives u an second option to verify your stream/latency, then u should know wich part produce the latency.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do the thig you have mentioned in your last paragraph?

Comment: use this tutorial =) https://www.thewindowsclub.com/play-rtsp-stream-via-command-line-interface-ffmpeg